# UI Automation Client-Side expose children of custom control

Tags: c#, wpf, accessibility, ui-automation, coded-ui-tests

I have a executable of an WPF application with custom controls which i need to run UI Tests on with Coded UI.

The custom controls do not implement accessibility / automation peers etc.
The app consists of a custom UserControl with a canvas inside, where mouse button clicks add ellipse shapes to the canvas. (I know this because i have the source code - but i need to implement client-side UIA support)

How can i implement a GetChildren method (as in the equivalent to FrameworkElementAutomationPeer.GetChildrenCore on server-side support) that will expose the control's (ellipse collection) children to be seen in the Coded UI Test Builder ?

Following the steps in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754059(v=vs.110).aspx, I tried implementing a Provider class which implements [IRawElementProviderSimple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.provider.irawelementprovidersimple(v=vs.110).aspx) but was unable to understand how to provide accessibility to the custom controls.

XAML :

```
<UserControl x:Name="ClientControl">
  <Canvas x:Name="ClientArea" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonUp="ClientArea_MouseLeftButtonUp"/>
</UserControl>
```